# Adobe Media Server - livepkgr application - restrict access to certain domains

Tags: flash, adobe, media, server, live-streaming

I'm testing to stream live via HTTP Dynamic Streaming (HDS).
Stream data is captured with Flash Media Live Encoder and send to the AMS Application 'livepkgr'. Everything is working as intended so far.

Now I want to restrict access to the stream similar to the 'vod' application. The 'vod' application provides:

- allowedHTMLdomains.txt
- allowedSWFdomains.txt

where you can enter domains like 'this.mydomain.net' and then only flash players started from these domains can connect and stream from the 'vod' application.

However allowedSWFdomains.txt, allowedSWFdomains.txt **do NOT work** with the /livepkgr/ application!

How do I restrict access to the 'livepkgr' application and stream similar to the above method?

As far as documents go, there seems to be only SWF verification and Adobe Accesss to secure livepkgr streams. Not what I was looking for.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with changing Adaptor.xml

```
<Adaptor>
...
    <Allow>this.mydomain.net</Allow>
    <Deny>all</Deny>
...
</Adaptor>
```